# How do I apply Deep Q learning to hyperparameter selection in XGBoost

Tags: xgboost

I want to do a sample unbalanced task, the current idea is to combine reinforcement Learning with machine learning algorithms, such as applying Deep Q Learning to XGBoost hyperparameter selection.

I know someone who has done similar projects, but I can't find a code reference for his project.